# Size of cardinal without choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How can we show that $ \aleph_0 \leq 2^{2^\kappa}$  for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$ without using the Axiom of Choice?

By Cantor's Theorem we can easily show that if $ \aleph_0 > 2^{2^\kappa}$, then $\aleph_0 > \kappa$.
Is there a way to conclude from this that $\kappa$ is finite without appealing to Choice? Thanks

Comment: Notice that, without choice, $\le$ is not necessarily total. We either have $\aleph_{0} \le 2^{2^\kappa}$ or ($\aleph_{0} \not \le 2^{2^{\kappa}} \not \le \aleph_{0}$).

Comment: Is it somehow, bizarrely, possible that choice fails but still $2^{2^\kappa}$ is the cardinality of an ordinal for every $\kappa$?

Comment: @Patrick No. If $2^{\kappa}$ is bijective to an ordinal, for every ordinal $\kappa$, then choice holds. (I believe its proof is due to Tarski.) If $2^{2^{\kappa}}$ bijective to an ordinal, for each ordinal $\kappa$, this implies that $2^{\kappa}$ is and hence it implies choice.

Answer (score 3):

You can define an injection $f:\mathbb N\to\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X))$ directly:
$$ f(n) = \{ A\subseteq X \mid \#A=n \} $$
since, by induction, an infinite set has subsets of every finite cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

The cardinal $m=2^{2^k} $ is infinite otherwise $k$ must be finite. Therefore $\aleph_0$ must be not greater than $m.$

Comment: This shows that $\aleph_0 \not> 2^{2^\kappa}$, but in the absence of Choice that does not imply $\aleph_0 \le 2^{2^\kappa}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it is necesarry to assume a axiom of choice to tell that if a set $A$ is infinite then $A$ contains a subset $B=\{a_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$?

Comment: x @Motyla: Yes -- it is consistent with ZF that there may exist a set that is not equinumerous with any natural, yet does not have any countably infinite subset.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Thats really interesting